# How to move the dropdown menu on top when resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have top menu with drop down navigation and drop down comes right side of main menu.

For Eg: `Purchased Items    Drop Down Menu`

```
                                     |-------------------|
            Purchased item           |  Dropdown Menu    |
                                     | ------------------|
```

When i resized, i want to move the drop down menu to top of the Purchased Item text.
Please suggest how to do this in html,js or jquery?
rchased

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label>Purchased Items </label> 
    <select name="select"> 
        <option>Milk</option>
        <option>Coffee</option> 
        <option>Tea</option> 
    </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML, CSS code for the menu so we can suggest solution/s

Comment: <div> <label>Purchased Items </label>
  <select name="select">
  <option>Milk</option>
  <option>Coffee</option>
  <option>Tea</option>
  </select>
  </div>

Comment: You really need to provide more than that. We need to see the page in full, whether on your server or via the full example code.

Answer (score 0):

Easily achievable via CSS, but you need to change the order of your HTML elements:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <select name="select"> 
        <option>Milk</option>
        <option>Coffee</option> 
        <option>Tea</option> 
    </select> 
    <label>Purchased Items </label> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
label { float: left; }
```

**Working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pWMn7/2/

You'll probably need to clear the float afterwards:

```
div { overflow: auto; } /* clears floats without the need for extra markup */
```

...and you'll likely need to give your div/label an id or class to stop the CSS being applied to *every* label and div on the page.